# How to get the current status of a javascript websocket connection

Tags: javascript, websocket, client

Sometimes when I restart the server or there is a network failure the websocket gets closed and I would like to be able to get the current connection status at all time.

I am basically getting the following error and I want to be able to predict it :

```
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state. 
    (anonymous function) 
    InjectedScript._evaluateOn 
    InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap 
    InjectedScript.evaluate
```

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This is very straightforward : the`readyState` property of the websocket contains the connection of the websocket at all times as specified in the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Ready_state_constants)

It will be one of the following values : `CONNECTING` `OPEN` `CLOSING` or `CLOSED`

A way to work around the error would be something like this :

```
if (yourWsObject.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED) {
   // Do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: the correct answer for the api. A small note, `yourWsObject.readyState` will be `1` (OPEN) even if you try to connect without connection. Ive tested it with a remote backend, trying to connect from an Android emulator. after closing Wifi on my laptop and trying to connect from the emulator to the remove socket server I still got    OPEN on `readyState`

Comment: socket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED && socket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSING ? true : false;

Comment: @BlueBot - Correct

Comment: Another option might be maintain a boolean by yourself, `onopen` -> `true`, `onclose` -> `false`.

Comment: @BlueBot correct it will say OPEN in any circumstances if error or closed is not met.
So i made 10 second interval to check if OPEN state is changed
AND AppState.addEventListener('change'); if previous state not active and new state active then force to reconnect.

Comment: I'd say to use `(yourWsObject.readyState == yourWsObject.OPEN)`, because sometimes, you can't predict whether the script will do soe crazy maneuvers and send a message when it's connecting.