# How to check if Websocket is open in Javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am testing the way web sockets work in Javascript,  tried the code this  way:

```
(function(){     
   socket = new Websocket('ws://achex.ca:4010');

   socket.onopen  =  function(){
        console.log("Connection is now open")
  }
})
```

Nothing appears in console  log...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current status of a javascript websocket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369368/how-to-get-the-current-status-of-a-javascript-websocket-connection)

Answer (score 5):

The`readyState` property of the websocket contains the connection of the websocket at all times as specified in the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Ready_state_constants)

It will be one of the following values : `CONNECTING` `OPEN` `CLOSING` or `CLOSED`

A way to work if it's open is :

```
if (yourWsObject.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
   // Do your stuff...
}
```